# Is there a way to differentiate between a user-caused event and an application-caused one?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events, combobox

This is mostly a dup of:

[Swing: Is there a way to differentiate between a user-caused ItemEvent and an application-caused one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176150/swing-is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-a-user-caused-itemevent-and-an-ap)

I think I have a case where it would be nice to tell the difference between user actions and programmatic actions. I am trying to write a general case thread safe JComboBox class. The idea being to hide away all the invokeLater stuff when trying to update a control from a non-AWT thread.

```
public class    JComboBoxThreadSafe
extends         JComboBox {

    private int m_iSelected = -1;
    private Object m_oSelected = null;
    private boolean m_bVisible = true;

    public JComboBoxThreadSafe(){

        super();

    }

    public JComboBoxThreadSafe(ComboBoxModel arg0){

        super(arg0);

    }

    public JComboBoxThreadSafe(Object[] items){

        super(items);

    }

    public JComboBoxThreadSafe(Vector<?> items){

        super(items);

    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedIndex(final int iIndex){

        m_iSelected = iIndex;
        m_oSelected = getItemAt(iIndex);

        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){

            super.setSelectedIndex(iIndex);

        }else{

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JComboBoxThreadSafe.super.setSelectedIndex(iIndex);

                }

            });


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(final Object oSelect){

        m_oSelected = oSelect;
        m_iSelected = FindItemIndex(oSelect);

        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){

            super.setSelectedItem(oSelect);

        }else{

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JComboBoxThreadSafe.super.setSelectedItem(oSelect);

                }

            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(final boolean bVisible){

        m_bVisible = bVisible;

        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){

            super.setVisible(bVisible);

        }else{

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    JComboBoxThreadSafe.super.setVisible(bVisible);

                }

            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem(){

        return m_oSelected;

    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedIndex(){

        return m_iSelected;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible(){

        return m_bVisible;

    }

    private int FindItemIndex(Object oItem){

        int iReturn = -1;

        int iCount = getItemCount();

        for (int iIndex = 0; (iReturn == -1) && (iIndex < iCount); iIndex++){

            if (getItemAt(iIndex).equals(oItem)) iReturn = iIndex;

        }

        return iReturn;

    }

}
```

I have a thread that is talking to a server across the network. When the GUI starts it queries the server for some settings. When it receives the response it needs to update the controls on the GUI. When the user changes the value, it sends the new setting to the server. Normally I would have a boolean flag to protect the programmatic set from causing the "new" setting being sent to the server. The change to the control happens later making the flag ineffective.

```
public class    DisplayOperatorAdvanced
implements      ListDataListener {

    private JComboBox m_cbRate = null;

    private boolean m_bAllowUpdates = true;

    public JPanel init(){

        // ... Lots of init stuff removed

        m_cbRate = new JComboBoxThreadSafe(...);
        m_cbRate.getModel().addListDataListener(this);

        // ... Lots of init stuff removed

    }

    private void setRate(){

        // Read control values and send them to server

    }

    public void handleSettingValue(String sSetting){

        // Comes in on a non-AWT thread

        m_bAllowUpdates = false;

        // The underlying control doesn't get changed until later!
        m_cbRate.setSelectedItem(sSetting);

        m_bAllowUpdates = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void contentsChanged(ListDataEvent ldeEvent){

        if (m_bAllowUpdates) setRate();

    }

}
```

I can think of a few hackish solutions:

1. Listen for mouse events instead of model changes
2. Try to filter out the next event after a programmatic change

It would be really nice to just filter out all programmatic changes. Can it be done?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here's a test class that shows that only modifying the model doesn't work. When I run this on the latest JDK, 1.7u51, and click the select random button the combbox doesn't render correctly. If you mouse over it it starts to work again until you make a new selection via the drop down and click the select random button again. So, I wrote JCmoboBoxThreadSafe in hope of not having to write invokeLater code every time I want to update a combobox.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class    CBTest
implements  ActionListener,
        Runnable {

    private static JComboBox<String> ms_cbTest = null;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aeEvent){

        Thread tThread = new Thread(this);

        tThread.start();

    }

    public void run(){

        ms_cbTest.getModel().setSelectedItem((int)(ms_cbTest.getItemCount() * Math.random()));

    }

    public static void main(String[] asArgs){

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        } catch (Exception e){
        }

        JFrame fFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel pPanel = new JPanel();

        fFrame.getContentPane().add(pPanel);

        ms_cbTest = new JComboBox<String>();

        for (int iNum = 0; iNum < 100; iNum++){

            ms_cbTest.addItem("" + iNum);

        }

        pPanel.add(ms_cbTest);

        JButton bSelect = new JButton("Select Random");

        bSelect.addActionListener(new CBTest());

        pPanel.add(bSelect);

        fFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        fFrame.pack();

        fFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        fFrame.setResizable(false);

        fFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Seriously, focus on the model, make it thread safe if you have to.  It's unlikely that the combobox itself will (or should) be modified in anyway other then on the EDT...

Comment: Normally there are 2 approaches 1) using the flag as you mentioned (I think it will work even with the multiple threads. You need to organize synch there). 2) Removing your listener before API call and adding it back after.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't think I explained what I'm trying to do with JComboBoxThreadSafe class. The whole point is so I can abstract away the invokeLater stuff there by only modifying it on the EDT.

Comment: The point is, the model is the only that should changing.  There should be no need to modify the state of the combobox out side of the EDT and if you are, then you have a bad design...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added some code that shows that only accessing the model still causes problems with JComboBox.

Comment: That's because you knowingly keep violating the single thread rules of Swing. The question is why are you changing that state of the combobox from a Thread?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have a thread doing socket IO to a server. When that thread receives a message it needs to update the GUI.

Comment: You seem to be going a long way around to solve a simple problem.  If you need to change the UI, then do it from within the context of the EDT.  This might require you to write a method that takes enough information in order to get it wrapped in a `invokeLater`, but trying to add thread-safety into a Swing component would be much more work, as you would need to fully understand all the areas that any one of those methods would change, including listener and event notification - but that's just my opinion...